# Retrieve Key value from Radiobutton in UI5 (xml View)

Tags: sapui5

```js
sap.ui.controller("test.controller", {
        
onInit: function() {
 var aData = {
        items: [
        {
          ATNAM: "FIORI_PRG",
          ATWRT: "BA",
          ATWTB: "Barcelona"
        }, {
          ATNAM: "FIORI_PRG",
          ATWRT: "BE",
          ATWTB: "Berlin"
        }, {
          ATNAM: "FIORI_PRG",
          ATWRT: "HA",
          ATWTB: "Havanna"
        }, {
          ATNAM: "FIORI_TYP",
          ATWRT: "SE",
          ATWTB: "Sessel"
        }, {
          ATNAM: "FIORI_TYP",
          ATWRT: "ZW",
          ATWTB: "Zweisitzer"
        }, {
          ATNAM: "FIORI_TYP",
          ATWRT: "DR",
          ATWTB: "Dreisitzer"
        }, {
          ATNAM: "FIORI_FARBE",
          ATWRT: "BL",
          ATWTB: "Blau"
        }, {
          ATNAM: "FIORI_FARBE",
          ATWRT: "BR",
          ATWTB: "Braun"
        }, {
          ATNAM: "FIORI_FARBE",
          ATWRT: "GR",
          ATWTB: "Grün"
        }, {
          ATNAM: "FIORI_FARBE",
          ATWRT: "SW",
          ATWTB: "Schwarz"
        }, {
          ATNAM: "FIORI_BEZUGSSTOFF",
          ATWRT: "ST",
          ATWTB: "Stoff"
        },  {
          ATNAM: "FIORI_BEZUGSSTOFF",
          ATWRT: "KL",
          ATWTB: "Kunstleder"
        },  {
          ATNAM: "FIORI_BEZUGSSTOFF",
          ATWRT: "NL",
          ATWTB: "Naturleder"
        } ],
      };

      var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
      oModel.setData(aData);
      sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel);
    },
  
radiobuttonselect:function(oEvent){
    var oSelectedIndex = oEvent.getParameter("selectedIndex");  
    var oRadioButtonSrc = oEvent.getSource().getAggregation("buttons");  
    var oSelectedRadio = oRadioButtonSrc[oSelectedIndex].getText();
//oRadioButtonSrc[oSelectedIndex].getKey(); does not work
    alert(oSelectedRadio);
 },
 
  });

    var oView = sap.ui.xmlview({
        viewContent: jQuery("#view1").html()
    });
    oView.placeAt("content");
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="description" content="OpenUI5 BIN Starting template" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" 
    type="text/javascript"
    data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.table,sap.ui.commons"
    data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal" src="https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"></script>
<script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
<sap.ui.core.mvc:View controllerName="test.controller"
    xmlns:c="sap.ui.commons"
    xmlns:k="sap.ui.core"
    xmlns:sap.ui.core.mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    
    
   <RadioButtonGroup xmlns="sap.m" id="Typ" buttons="{/items}" width="500px" columns="1" enabled="true" class="sapUiMediumMarginBottom" select="radiobuttonselect"> 
      <buttons>                                                    <RadioButton id="RBG1" text="{ATWTB}" key="{ATWRT}"/>
      </buttons>                                         </RadioButtonGroup>
</sap.ui.core.mvc:View>

</script>

  <title>buttons Vs Combobox</title>
</head>

<body class="sapUiBody">
  <div id="content"></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Hello Experts,
this question is about to retrieve a key value from a radiobutton. To retrieve the text is possible (as in the snippet above), but I am having a hard time getting the key value (here is my attempt: http://jsbin.com/yoxube/edit?html,js,output) . Is it possible? what would be the way? thank you in advance and best regards,
Gabriel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi,

Here how I would do it (I'll just post here your updated `radiobuttonselect()` function):

```js
radiobuttonselect:function(oEvent){
    var oSelectedIndex = oEvent.getParameter("selectedIndex");  
    var oRadioButtonSrc = oEvent.getSource().getAggregation("buttons");  
    var oModel = sap.ui.getCore().getModel();  
    var sKey = oModel.getProperty("/items/"+oSelectedIndex+"/ATWRT"); 
    alert(sKey);
},
```

Here is a working JSBIN: [LINK](http://jsbin.com/hanadofuco/1/edit?js,output)

Comment: Thank you very much. The concepts of getCore and getModel are the ones I still must learn. Thank you again

Comment: @GabrielGomez you're welcome! Feel free to tag the answer as correct;)

Comment: Hi @keshet off course I have tried but the system does not allow me yet. Once I obtain the 15 reputation points I will tag your answer as correct. Thank you again.